# Touch event on TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, overlay

I have a requirement where I need to display an overlay over screen lock and subscribe to touch event on TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY. But from the forums, I see that this is no longer possible (i.e. subscribing to touch events on overlay).

I cannot change to Type_Phone as that is not showing up over screen lock. (I have experimented a few types and only overlay is showing up on screen lock). Any thoughts on how this can be achieved?

```
    mWindowManager = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
            mView = LayoutInflater.from(getApplicationContext()).inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, null);
        WindowManager.LayoutParams mLayoutParams = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 0, 0,
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY,
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED
                            | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD
                            | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON,
                    PixelFormat.RGBA_8888);
mWindowManager.addView(touchLayout, mLayoutParams);
```

...

```
view.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                if (event.getActionMasked() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                    Log.i("Spot", "xyz..");
                }
                return true;
            }
        });
```

Basically, I want to implement something similar to what happens when power button is pressed. The system triggers an overlay (on top of the lock screen) and on tap the device shuts down

Comment: Hopefully it can't be achieved. Allowing malware authors "to display an overlay over screen lock and subscribe to touch event" would be a really big security flaw.

Comment: Android itself does it when you press the power button.  So this can be achieved. The question is how are they doing it?

Comment: "Android itself does it when you press the power button" -- or, possibly, that is part of the lockscreen itself. Regardless, it is part of the core firmware, and what you want should not be possible for ordinary SDK apps, for blindingly obvious security reasons.

Comment: Did you try it with TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT oder TYPE_SYSTEM_ERROR?

Comment: Were you able to get this working? I know a lot of time has gone by, but was facing exactly the same issue.

Comment: It's a shame this question got hijacked by the first commenter. It would be nice to get an answer. TYPE_PHONE causes overlays not not receive key-presses yet so many overlay apps do and they're not all "security flaws" particularly given there is a permission grant required

Comment: Unfortunately I haven't found a way to get this working so I gave up on this